# How to remove same value if it has in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Ho do I remove same values in an array has?

example code:

```
const array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 70, 10 ]
```

Expected output:

```
const outputArray = [30, 40, 70];
```

I can remove the duplicate value. But how to remove both the duplicate values.

Duplicate remove code:

```
const removeDuplicate = [...new Set(array)];
```

After the removed duplicate output is below mentioned.

```
const outputArray = [10, 20, 30, 40, 70];
```

But I want to remove both the duplicate values and will get the expected output

```
const outputArray = [30, 40, 70];
```